# Sony SmartWatch crash reports

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have a number of smartwatch apps.  They all behaive as expected for me but I am getting intermittent crash reports from ACRA in the smartwatch library code.  No reference to anything in my code so I don't know if there is anything I can do about the issue.

Anyone from Sony got any ideas?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndex(AbstractCursor.java:249)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndex(CursorWrapper.java:73)
    at com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.e.a(SourceFile:263)
    at com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.c.e.c(SourceFile:154)
    at com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.c.e.b(SourceFile:116)
    at com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.c.e.doInBackground(SourceFile:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    ... 5 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndex(AbstractCursor.java:249)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndex(CursorWrapper.java:73)
    at com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.e.a(SourceFile:263)
    at com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.c.e.c(SourceFile:154)
    at com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.c.e.b(SourceFile:116)
    at com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util.c.e.doInBackground(SourceFile:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Interesting! There is no typical sequence of events that are involved, that you know of? Can you name one of your apps for reference, so I could check?

Comment: I am generally not getting much in the log.  I suspect it's happening at start-up but have not reproduced it myself or had direct contact from any users where I think this is the issue.  IpBike is my main app IpSmartHr and IpSmartAltimeter are also showing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as comment, but I don't have the reputation...

How many different phones are you testing with? Hopefully, you have a few, from few different makers (i.e. they're not only Samsung, for example). I've seen something similar happen to my apps running on a Sony phone, and not on an LG.

Comment: Only tested on X8 and Active.  I have a Nexus 4 now for adding Btle support so will dig out the Smartwatch and check with that as well.  Need to test the HR app works with the Nexus 4 and BTLE anyway as it's an interesting corner case classic Bluetooth and Btle at the same time.